# Re-using provider functionality from angular ui-router resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app where I have created a provider that I use for getting the user and authorization.  In my app.config I setup routes with ui-router.  For the first route I am using the resolve property to ensure that it will only load if the user has the admin role.  For the second route I want to do the same thing except have it require the customer role. I want to use the exact same code as I do for checking the admin role but just substitute `role='customer'`.  Is there a way to do this without duplicating the `requireAdminRole` code?  I tried to figure out a way to pass the required role from the ui-router `resolve` definition to the provider as a parameter but I couldn't figure it out.

My provider definition:

```
angular.module('users').provider('Authentication', ['$windowProvider', function($windowProvider) {
    var _this = this;
    var $window = $windowProvider.$get();
    _this.data = {user: $window.user};

    this.$get = function () {
        return _this.data;
    };

    this.requireAdminRole = ['$q', '$state', '$timeout', function ($q, $state) {
        var role = 'admin';
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (_this.data.user.roles.indexOf(role) < 0) {
            $timeout(function() {
                deferred.reject();
                $state.go('root');
            }, 100);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(_this.data.user);
        }
        return deferred.promise;        
    }];

}]);
```

My routes:

```
angular.module('customer').config(['$stateProvider', 'AuthenticationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, AuthenticationProvider){
        $stateProvider.
        state('listCustomers', {
            url: 'admin/customers',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'modules/customer/views/admin/list-customers.client.view.html',
                    controller: 'CustomerAdminController as customerCtrl'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                CurrentUser: AuthenticationProvider.requireAdminRole
            }
        }).
        state('survey', {
            url: 'customers/survey',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'modules/customer/views/view-customer.client.view.html',
                    controller: 'CustomerAdminController as customerCtrl'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                CurrentUser:  // This is where I want to reuse code from requireAdminRole
            }
        });
```